# Unable to load dll error

Tags: c#, exception, dll

i am working project in c# Visual studio 2009,i am using c++ dll in my project and also i call that dll through my function . In my system the project run successfully.but in other system not in single system more than system i checked it shows exception like unable to load dll. i am check that dll in dependency walker it shows msvcr71.dll is missing.how i get this.?i need better solution for this

Comment: There is a Visual Studio 2009 o_O

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your native C++ DLL depends on the library msvcr71.dll.  This is not part of the standard windows installed hence you must take some action to get it onto the target machine.

The simplest way to do this is to just copy the DLL around with your application.  The following [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326922) covers this.

Documentation on msvcr71.dll

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing something in your installation of the SDK (or Visual Studio). I would recommend a Repair or Reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

look on msdn for info about redistributables - this tell you what you need to install on a non dev box to make things work

Answer (score 0):

This is not programming related. You are missing a dll file on your target system. Download and put in "windows/System32" and it should run.